# Proving that there is no translation invariant measure on the $P(\mathbb R^2) $

Tags: real-analysis

I try to show that there is no function like $\mu$ on $\mathbb R^2$ satisfying measure conditions and for any tow set if $E$ is congruent to $ F$, then $ \mu (E) = \mu (F) $ and $\mu([0,1]*[0,1]) =1$. In Folland he showed this for $\mathbb R$
Now I want to find a similar proof for $\mathbb R^2$.

In Folland we have an equivalent relation on [0,1) that is $x$~$y$ iff $x-y \in Q$ and with this relation we reach a contradiction .
Can someone help me please, thanks.

Comment: Show that you could construct a translation invariant measure on $\mathbb R$ from such a measure.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos i want show that on R^2 not on R

Comment: The idea is that if you manage to show that the existence of such a measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$ would imply the existence of such a measure on $\mathbb{R}$, then, since you already know that none can exist on $\mathbb{R}$, you will have proved that none can exist on $\mathbb{R}^2$.